# CoreData: Different Results between NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType and managedObjectResultType

Tags: swift, dictionary, core-data, nsfetchrequest

i have 2 requests. One calls the objects, one the objects as dictionary. 
the First one, that calls the objects is completly fine. everythin works extremely well. 
But the one to get dictionary... 
19 of 20 properties are quite fine. But one is strange.

At the model the "autoAddToPlaylist" is a int16, not optional, with default value. Inside the result dictionary sometimes it is completely missing, or shows the wrong value. 
I work with the propertiesToFetch option on my FetchRequest

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName: "ManagedPodcast")
fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType
fetchRequest.includesSubentities = false

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title",
                                           ascending: true,
                                            selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare))]

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "paused == 0")

fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = true

let objectIdDesc = NSExpressionDescription()
    objectIdDesc.name = "objectID"
    objectIdDesc.expression = NSExpression.expressionForEvaluatedObject()
    objectIdDesc.expressionResultType = .objectIDAttributeType

fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [objectIdDesc, "feed", "title", "autoAddToPlaylist", ... (more properties, all strings)]

fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 3
fetchRequest.fetchOffset = 0

do {
    let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

} catch let error as NSError {
    log("getAll ERROR: ", error.localizedDescription)
}
```